# Fingerprint module Command packets doesn't send response to smt32f4

Tags: arm, stm32, fingerprint, stm32f4discovery, usart

Hı everyone
I am currently working on fingerprint module(fpm10).I read so many datasheet but every datasheet have different command packets I referenced R305 datasheet after that I wrote a Code for command packet to send STM32 but fpm10 doesnt send response to stm32.This is my verifypassword command packet Module send my receive my command packet but doesnt response.I debuged my cod and ı havent get any error

```
uint16_t  FP_Verify_Password[16]={0xEF,0x01,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0x01,0x00,0x07,0x13,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x05};

void Finger_Get_img(void)
{ 
        delay_ms(500);
    if(my_finger==true)
     {
       //only one time will be apply
          for(i=6 ; i<=13 ; i++)
          checksum+=FP_Verify_Password[i];
          FP_Verify_Password[14]=checksum&0xFF00;
          FP_Verify_Password[15]=checksum&0x00FF;
     }
     for(i=0;i<16;i++)   
     {
     // USART_SendData(USART2,FP_Pack_Head[i]);
          delay_ms(50);
          USART_Finger(USART1,FP_Verify_Password[i]);
          delay_ms(50);
          USART_Finger(USART6,FP_Verify_Password[i]);
          delay_ms(50);
    }
    
    delay_ms(2000);
    
   // GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOG,GPIO_Pin_13);
    my_finger=false;
}
```

Bluetooth and Finger print module config

```
 //fingerprint module configurations
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_USART1,ENABLE);
  
  USART_InitStruct.USART_BaudRate=57600;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_HardwareFlowControl=USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_Mode=USART_Mode_Rx|USART_Mode_Tx;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_Parity=USART_Parity_No;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_StopBits=USART_StopBits_1;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_WordLength=USART_WordLength_8b;
  
  USART_Init(USART1,&USART_InitStruct);
  
  USART_Cmd(USART1,ENABLE);
  
  USART_ITConfig(USART1,USART_IT_RXNE,ENABLE);
 
//bluetooth module configurations
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC,ENABLE);
  
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC,GPIO_PinSource6,GPIO_AF_USART6);
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC,GPIO_PinSource7,GPIO_AF_USART6);
    
  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_OType=GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_6|GPIO_Pin_7;
  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_PuPd=GPIO_PuPd_UP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed=GPIO_Speed_100MHz;
  
  GPIO_Init(GPIOC,&GPIO_InitStruct);
  
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_USART6,ENABLE);
  
  USART_InitStruct.USART_BaudRate=9600;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_HardwareFlowControl=USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_Mode=USART_Mode_Rx|USART_Mode_Tx;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_Parity=USART_Parity_No;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_StopBits=USART_StopBits_1;
  USART_InitStruct.USART_WordLength=USART_WordLength_8b;
  
  USART_Init(USART6,&USART_InitStruct);
  
  USART_Cmd(USART6,ENABLE);
```

This my command packet

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to help you. You need to isolate your problem more precisely. For example: how do you know if the fingerprint module does not respond or if your code does not get this response ? Did you use a logic analyser to be sure you send the right data to the fingerprint ? etc...

Comment: I am sorry you are right.I changed my post now.